# Reactjs if conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I control the loop in `reactjs`? I just want that if the label or `Group` is equal it will not be displayed

```
generateAvailableOptions(data){
    const availableGroups = [];
    data.map(function(food){
        availableGroups.push({
                label: food.Group,
                options: [
                    { value: 'canAdd'+food.groupsid, label: food.description}
                ],
        })
    });
    this.setState({availableGroups: availableGroups})
}
```

The actual result

```
   Vegetables:
         Carrots
   Vegetables:
         Cabbage
   Vegetables:
         Potato
   Fruits:
         Mango
   Fruits:
         Apple
   Fruits:
         Pineapple
```

This is what I want results:

```
   Vegetables:
         Carrots
         Cabbage
         Potato
   Fruits:
         Mango
         Apple
         Pineapple
```

Comment: whta is structure of `Vegetables:
         Carrots
   Vegetables:
         Cabbage
   Vegetables:
         Potato` is it object? or array of object?

Comment: that is the result of data from the database

Comment: You mean it is json?

Comment: yes it is......

Comment: This is not valid object because you have multiple key in one object

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi, so what should i do to achieve what result i desired?

Comment: Can you share value of data in its format. I mean the data you got form db

Comment: is it possible to add if condition when the label is equal to the label like (fruits === fruits) then it will not print or display?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235249/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-kaito).

Comment: Your Logic is incorrect. do this instead: 1. extract all distinct food.Group into an array initialising objects like `{label: food.Group, options: [] }`
2. inside `data.map.(function (..` iterate over the above initialized array and match `if (food.Group === arrElem.label)`
3. if matches, just `arrElem.options.push({ value: 'canAdd'+food.groupsid, label: food.description})`

Comment: @PranayNailwal can you please post your answer? so that I can Understand clearly

Comment: Could you please share your data which you give into `generateAvailableOptions`?

Comment: @kaito I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
const data = [
            {Group:'vegetable',description:'Carrots',groupsid:1},        
            {Group:'vegetable',description:'Cabbage',groupsid:1},
            {Group:'vegetable',description:'Potato',groupsid:1},       
            {Group:'fruit',description:'Mango',groupsid:2},        
            {Group:'fruit',description:'Apple',groupsid:2}
          ]
generateAvailableOptions(data){
    const result = data.reduce((item,curr)=> {
               if(!item[curr.Group]) item[curr.Group] = [];
                item[curr.Group].push({value: 'canAdd'+curr.groupsid, label: curr.description});
                return item;
            },{});
    
    const availableGroups = [];
    Object.entries(result).forEach(entry => {
      const [key, value] = entry;
        availableGroups.push({
        "label":key,
        "options": value
      })
    });
   this.setState({availableGroups: availableGroups});
}
```

You can see the result : https://es6console.com/krhjx0rz/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to group by your array based on keys.

You can use `Object.keys` to get key of all object and then check to see if exists or not. if exists push new value if not assign to current array value.

So try this one:

```js
var data = [{ "Vegetables": "Carrots" }, { "Vegetables": "Cabbage" }, { "Vegetables": "Potato", }, { "Fruits": "Mango" }, { "Fruits": "Apple" },{ "Fruits": "Pineapple" }]


var obj = {};

for (let a in data) {
    let keys = Object.keys(data[a]);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (obj[keys[i]])
            obj[keys[i]].push(data[a][keys[i]])
        else
            obj[keys[i]] = [data[a][keys[i]]];
    }
    
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
  { Group: "Veg", description: "potato", groupsid: 1 },
  { Group: "Veg", description: "cucumber", groupsid: 1 },
  { Group: "Fruit", description: "tomato", groupsid: 2 }
];
function generateAvailableOptions(data) {
  const distinctFoodObjs = [];
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  data.map((item) => {
    var findItem = distinctFoodObjs.find((x) => x.Group === item.Group);
    if (!findItem) distinctFoodObjs.push({ label: item.Group, options: [] });
  });
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  data.map((food) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    distinctFoodObjs.map((arrElem) => {
      if (arrElem.label === food.Group) {
        arrElem.options.push({
          value: "canAdd" + food.groupsid,
          label: food.description
        });
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(distinctFoodObjs);
}
generateAvailableOptions(data);
```